# How to customize m2e-wtp deployment?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, m2e-wtp

In my project, I have some aar dependencies. I don't want deploy these aar files into the WEB-INF/lib folder. I want to deploy them in some other folders. But I can't find where to set the m2e-wtp plugin do this.

My pom file is like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-soap</artifactId>
  <type>aar</type>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
  <webResources>
    <webResource>
   <directory>${settings.localRepository}/my.group/my-soap/1.0.0/</directory>
    <targetPath>destination/folder</targetPath><!-- optional, will deploy at the root of the webapp by default-->
    <includes>
      <include>*.aar</include>
    </includes>
   </webResource>
  </webResources>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```